# kivy label position differences

Tags: python, label, kivy

I've tried seek in the internet solving my problem. But it has no result at all.
So. Please look at this code sample:

```
class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        btn = Button(text='Hello world')
        btn.size_hint = (1, .3)
        btn.pos_hint = {'top':1}
        title = Label(text=('[color=ff3333]Hello world[/color]'),
                          font_size=str(12) + 'sp', markup=True)
        self.add_widget(title)
        self.add_widget(btn)
        title.texture_update()
        title.text_size = (Window.width, None)
        title.height = title.texture_size[1]
        with title.canvas:
                Color(1., 1., 0)
                Rectangle(size=title.size, pos=title.pos)
        print(title.size)
        print(title.pos)
        print(title.texture_size)
```

And now look at image:

[image: Label position]

Can anyone tell me why print(title.pos) say (0,0), canvas draw rectangle at (0,0) but text appear at another position?

I've already overwhelmed with this...

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to see differences between a `Widget` as a "container" like thing and its content - what's drawn on the canvas. A `Widget` needs to take some space and so it does.

The important defaults for a `Widget` are:

- position   `[0, 0]`
- size_hint `[1, 1]`
- size         `[100, 100]`

What you did:

1. change text size to `[800 (by default), None]`

   ```
   title.text_size = (Window.width, None)
   ```
2. set height of a Widget to take the same height as the rendered text has

   ```
   title.height = title.texture_size[1]
   ```

These changes didn't do anything with the container, because you forgot a basic thing in this layout, which is:

> FloatLayout honors the pos_hint and the size_hint properties of its children.

Therefore either put `size_hint_y=None` into kwargs or do `title.size_hint_y=None` *before* setting height for the first time. When `size_hint` is properly set/removed from the way, you can manipulate the container, which if used correctly:

```
title = Label(...)
title.size_hint=[None, None]
title.size = title.texture_size
```

makes the container encapsulate the rendered text. This makes the rendered text's position the same position which has the container (`Widget`).

Note: When encountering similar stuff, printing is *nice*, yet not as useful as using [`Inspector`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.inspector.html) module, mainly for positioning/sizing/<any layout related thing> debugging:

```
python main.py -m inspector
```

Comment: It's work, but with one line: 'title.texture_update()' after setting size_hint. I'll read more kivy documentation. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

the `title` `Label` is located inside of the `FloatLayout` `Widget` where `title.canvas` is drawing from.  This is why the `title.pos` is `(0,0)`.   `title.text` is the actual position you are looking for, but the problem with that is `title.text` is a string and doesn't have a `pos` attribute :/

Comment: Hello. Thank you for reply. Please, read answer above. It's work.